# Is it appropriate to ask about Zorin OS here, as it's built on Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if the issue is with Ubuntu or if it's with Zorin but when I try to add my Facebook account with the GNOME Online Accounts menu, I get this error message:

`Error getting identity: Could not parse response`

I would like to ask about this on AU but I realise that it is Zorin ***OS*** and things aren't going to run *exactly* the same way as with Ubuntu. Their website does say, "Built on an Ubuntu Linux foundation, Zorin OS runs on the same Open Source software [as systems from the U.S. D.O.D to stuff on the I.S.S.]"

It is very obvious that it relies heavily on Ubuntu GNOME; it has the GNOME Control Panel, GNOME Extensions, GNOME Software, GNOME Indicators, and other features that are GNOME specific as well.

Comment: Granted, I'm not necessarily sure that I like our policy, but it does help to keep the site clean.... but *shrug*

Comment: I do understand lol. Thank you.

Comment: From my own experience with Zorin OS and, also, from what I've noticed on Linux Mint forums, I can say that the similarities between the distros may vary very much. I mean, if you run Zorin OS, then AskUbuntu will help you in 90% of cases, Unix & Linux in 5%, and Zorin OS forum or other Zorin OS specific sites, in the rest of 5% cases. Whereas, if you run Linux Mint, well, then you'll have to manage with Unix & Linux and the Mint Linux official or unofficial websites. AskUbuntu will not be much of help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** We don't support Linux Mint or any other distros which are based on Ubuntu here either.

You could ask on our sister site, http://unix.stackexchange.com though.

---

We only support [official Ubuntu flavors](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours), such as:

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu GNOME
- Kubuntu
- Xubuntu
- Lubuntu
- Ubuntu MATE